# Get product by name in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model

How to get product by name? I have the name of the product in my code and iIwant to get product so I use this code :

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = $model->load('name-of-product','product_name');
```

To get product but it return a null `object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)` iIuse this code for other models and it worked but for `'catalog/product'` not working. How to get product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name', $productName);
```

**Note:** Make sure your name attribute code is proper.

**In addition**

`loadByAttribute()` basically loads the product collection and filter those collection by attribute you have specified and then it is returns the collection first item.

```
$collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
    ->setPage(1,1);
```

Comment: thank u it worked !!

Comment: Does not work for me on Magento 1.9.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope it's helpful to you.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%'.$search.'%')
                        )
                    )
                    ->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but return null object

Comment: check it updated answer....it is working..

Comment: Instead of load() use getFirstItem() so it returns only the first result